# Android In-App Billing: String payload

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement In-App Billing in my App and in the [google payload sample's MainActivity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/MainActivity.java) it says like this:

> /* TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See the comments on
>            *        verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is a SAMPLE, we just use
>            *        an empty string, but on a production app you should carefully generate this. */

I have looked for it on [Android Developers - Security and Design](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html) and it states:

> You should pass in a string token that helps your application to identify the user who made the purchase, so that you can later verify that this is a legitimate purchase by that user. For consumable items, you can use a randomly generated string, but for non- consumable items you should use a string that uniquely identifies the user.

Still it is not clear to me how do I have to generate the String and most importantly how to **"use a string that uniquely identifies the user"**

Perhaps you can provide an example and a brief explanation of how it works.

**EDIT:**
Google in the [Android Developers - Security and Design](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html) even suggests not to use the user email.

> Note: Do not use the user's email address in the payload string, since that address may change.

What can I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to android documentation here it is stated that

The fifth argument contains a ‘developer payload’ string that you can use to send supplemental information about an order (it can be an empty string). Typically, this is used to pass in a string token that uniquely identifies this purchase request. If you specify a string value, Google Play returns this string along with the purchase response. Subsequently, when you make queries about this purchase, Google Play returns this string together with the purchase details.

Security Recommendation: It’s good practice to pass in a string that helps your application to identify the user who made the purchase, so that you can later verify that this is a legitimate purchase by that user. For consumable items, you can use a randomly generated string, but for non-consumable items you should use a string that uniquely identifies the user.

So , For the product ID SKU_2006 if you initiated the purchase flow with String payload = email+item1; then Google Play will return the same payload in the response and hence you would get it here as

```
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
..
}
```

Now , let me define the whole scenario in terms of code :

First , you would initiate a purchase request like below

```
String payload = getUserEmailFromAndroidAccounts() + itemUniqueId;

mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(new PurchaseFinishListener(itemUniqueId), SKU_GAS, 10001,   
   mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

If the purchase order is successful, the response data from Google Play is stored in an Purchase object that is passed back to the listener.

```
 private class PurchaseFinishListener implements IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener {
   private final String mItemUniqeId;
    public PurchaseFinishListener(String itemUniqeId) {

            mItemUniqeId = itemUniqeId;
        }

       public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) 
       {
          if (result.isFailure()) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
             return;
          }      
    if (!verifyDeveloperPayLoad(mItemUniqeId , purchase)) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Authenticity verification failed");
             return;
    }

    // set your product as purchased in your DB or server

    }
    }
```

Now your verifyDeveloperPayLoad(purchase) method should look as below :

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Is there something I could use to identify the user other than his email? because google is suggesting not to use it as it may change.

Comment: I have implement a similar algorithm. But got hacked with one click of "Lukcy Patcher" application. Do you know any approach to prevent the hacking?